# Google Sheets JavaScript - TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheetName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-java-format

I've got an identical script running on three google sheets, it works just fine on two of them, but on one it just won't generate, keeps throwing me the below error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheetName' of undefined

[Here's a version that you can play around with if you like](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wWNfO2nrFWnHlTYoCOlRks73N3fs62HNako3BKBpBjU/edit#gid=657745084)

Here's the script:

```js
var masterSheetName = "GROUP 1";
var ignoreThisSheets=masterSheetName+ ",REFERENCE,";
var sortColumn=4;
var sortAscending = true;
function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
    ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
        .addItem('Generate Master Sheet', 'menuItem1')
        .addToUi();

}

function menuItem1() {
  //  insertFinalSheet();
    collectDataFromSheets(masterSheetName);
}


function getRangeFromSheetsToCopy(thissheet, skipRows, skipCols) {
    return thissheet.getRange(skipRows, skipCols, thissheet.getLastRow(), thissheet.getLastColumn());
}

function insertFinalSheet() {
    var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var itt = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(masterSheetName);

    if (itt) {
        activeSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(itt);
    }
    activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet(masterSheetName);
}


function collectDataFromSheets(masterSheetName) {

    var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = activeSpreadsheet.getSheets();
    var masterSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(masterSheetName);
var range = masterSheet.getRange(2,1,masterSheet.getLastRow(),masterSheet.getLastColumn());
range.clear();
    var colValues = [];
    var first = true;
        console.log("Sheets : " + sheets);
        console.log("activeSpreadsheet : " + activeSpreadsheet);

    for ([i, sheet] in sheets) {
               console.log("i : " + i);
 var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
        console.log("Working on sheet: " +sheetName);

      if(ignoreThisSheets.indexOf(sheetName)>= 0){
        console.log("Skipping sheet: " +sheetName);
        continue;
      } 

            var currentSheetRange;
            // Get the range of the sheet that is your paste target.
            var pasteRange;
            console.log('masterSheet.getLastRow() is:' + masterSheet.getLastRow())
            console.log('masterSheet.getLastColumn() is:' + masterSheet.getLastColumn())
            console.log('sheet.getLastRow() is:' + sheet.getLastRow())
            console.log('sheet.getLastColumn() is:' + sheet.getLastColumn())
     

              //  currentSheetRange = getRangeFromSheetsToCopy(sheet, 1, 1);
     currentSheetRange =   sheet.getRange(2, 1, getLastRow(sheet), sheet.getLastColumn());
          if(first)
                pasteRange = masterSheet.getRange(2,1);
          else
                pasteRange = masterSheet.getRange(getLastRow(masterSheet)+1, 1);
          
            var columnWidths = SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL;
            currentSheetRange.copyTo(pasteRange);
            currentSheetRange.copyTo(pasteRange, columnWidths, false);

            first = false;
      
       masterSheet.getRange(2,1,masterSheet.getLastRow(),  masterSheet.getLastColumn()).sort({column: sortColumn, ascending: sortAscending});

       
    }

    return colValues;
}
function getLastRow(sheet){
         var Avals = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
                 console.log('Avals is:' + Avals)
 var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
                      console.log('Alast is:' + Alast);
  return Alast;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line below all the elements are `null`, therefore, that's the reason you are getting the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheetName' of undefined` error message.

```
for ([i, sheet] in sheets)
```

You can change your `for` loop like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheetName = sheets[i].getSheetName();
    Logger.log("Working on sheet: " + sheetName);

    if (ignoreThisSheets.indexOf(sheetName) >= 0) {
        Logger.log("Skipping sheet: " + sheetName);
        continue;
    }

    var currentSheetRange;
    // Get the range of the sheet that is your paste target.
    var pasteRange;
    Logger.log('masterSheet.getLastRow() is:' + masterSheet.getLastRow())
    Logger.log('masterSheet.getLastColumn() is:' + masterSheet.getLastColumn())
    Logger.log('sheets[i].getLastRow() is:' + sheets[i].getLastRow())
    Logger.log('sheets[i].getLastColumn() is:' + sheets[i].getLastColumn())


    //  currentSheetRange = getRangeFromSheetsToCopy(sheet, 1, 1);
    currentSheetRange = sheets[i].getRange(2, 1, getLastRow(sheets[i]), sheets[i].getLastColumn());
    if (first)
        pasteRange = masterSheet.getRange(2, 1);
    else
        pasteRange = masterSheet.getRange(getLastRow(masterSheet) + 1, 1);

    var columnWidths = SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL;
    currentSheetRange.copyTo(pasteRange);
    currentSheetRange.copyTo(pasteRange, columnWidths, false);

    first = false;

    masterSheet.getRange(2, 1, masterSheet.getLastRow(), masterSheet.getLastColumn()).sort({
        column: sortColumn,
        ascending: sortAscending
    });


}
```

Moreover, in `Apps Script`, if you want to `log` a `value`, you can use `Logger.log(value)` and you should see all the logged values if you check the `Logs`.